# How to properly mutate a vector behind a Mutex in Rust

Tags: rust, mutex

I have a stuct that looks like this:

```rust
pub struct Coordinator {
    map_tasks: Mutex<Vec<Task>>,
    reduce_tasks: Mutex<Vec<Task>>,
}
```

And I have a function that is called with a parameter to determine which of the two vectors to modify. The function takes a type and an id to find in the vector and modify. My original approach is this:

```rust
impl Coordinator {
    pub fn update_status(&self, task_type: TaskType, task_id: u8) {
        if task_type == TaskType::Map {
            let tasks = &mut self.map_tasks.lock().unwrap();
            for task in tasks.iter_mut() {
                if task.task_id == task_id {
                    task.status = TaskStatus::Success;
                }
            }
        } else {
            let tasks = &mut self.reduce_tasks.lock().unwrap();
            for task in tasks.iter_mut() {
                if task.task_id == task_id {
                    task.status = TaskStatus::Success;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to shorten the code since a lot of it is duplicated. I've tried this, but it doesnt work with the error `temporary value dropped while borrowed, consider using a "let" binding to create a longer lived value`

```rust
impl Coordinator {
    pub fn update_status(&self, task_type: TaskType, task_id: u8) {
        let tasks;
        if task_type == TaskType::Map {
            tasks = &mut self.map_tasks.lock().unwrap();
        } else {
            tasks = &mut self.reduce_tasks.lock().unwrap();
        }

        for task in tasks.iter_mut() {
            if task.task_id == task_id {
                task.status = TaskStatus::Success;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: I believe this is an interaction between the rule (that I can't cite, sorry) where temporaries are extended to the life of the enclosing scope.  The temporary here being the result of `lock()`.  But now that you're going outside of that scope, the compiler is complaining.  If somebody can cite that better, I suggest posting an answer that explains it better than my faulty memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to take a mutable reference into the guard, you can just store the guard directly. Also, `if..else` is an expression, you can use it as a ternary:

```rust
impl Coordinator {
    pub fn update_status(&self, task_type: TaskType, task_id: u8) {
        let mut tasks = if task_type == TaskType::Map {
            self.map_tasks.lock().unwrap()
        } else {
            self.reduce_tasks.lock().unwrap()
        };

        for task in tasks.iter_mut() {
            if task.task_id == task_id {
                task.status = TaskStatus::Success;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this a lot. I keep forgetting that if/else is an expression that I can use this way.  Very clean.  I could also see taking a reference to the field you want and assigning a reference to that, and then doing `.lock().unwrap()` on a later line, but I think most people would find your way cleaner.